# How to insert special character in a string given a full list in Python?

Tags: python, python-re

I have a list that contains some strings that have '\' in them.

Ex:

```
'PEOPLE\\S BANK', 'PRIME MINISTER\\S'
```

I would like to add a single quote after every string that contains a \ in them.

Ive tried

```
import re
tt = re.sub(r'(\\)', r'\1"', str(updated_unique_accts))
```

This just adds a " between each . Any thoughts? There are multiple strings that contain this pattern.

### Desired output

```
'PEOPLE\'S BANK', 'PRIME MINISTER\'S'
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use replace function.

```
updated_unique_accts = ['PEOPLE\\S BANK', 'PRIME MINISTER\\S']
new_strings = []
for i in updated_unique_accts:
    new_string = i.replace("\\", "\\'") 
    new_strings.append(new_string)
print(new_strings)
```

O/P : ["PEOPLE\'S BANK", "PRIME MINISTER\'S"]

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, you just need to remember that both `'` and `"` can be used for strings in python:

```py
for line in updated_unique_accts:
    tt = re.sub(r'(\\\\)', r"\1'", line)
```

Comment: Is there a way to just add it after the second \? My results is as follows: 'PEOPLE\'\'S BANK', 'PRIME MINISTER\'\'S'

Comment: You need four backslashes in your regex then.

Comment: @Dinho fyi this solution is roughly 10 times slower than the one using `replace`

Comment: Is there a way to just have a single \ instead of \\? @alex

Comment: @Dinho in the output? sure, but that's not what you said in the _**Desired output**_ in the question

Comment: I am just now realizing that..@alex sorry

Comment: updated and did not close the post - sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
input_ = ['PEOPLE\\S BANK', 'PRIME MINISTER\\S']
output_ = [i.replace('\\', '\\\'') for i in input_]
```

which gives

```
["PEOPLE\\'S BANK", "PRIME MINISTER\\'S"]
```